# How does Rust calculate lifetime of a moved value?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow

In Rust, the lifetime of a value is between the point of definition and the point of going out of scope.

However the out of scope can be the end of a statement that *steals* the value.

Rust respects this only partially. Why?

Take this example:

```
// This is the starting point, it compiles without errors/warnings, but does not do what it should.
struct Inner{x : i32}

struct Outer<'e>{
    s : &'e Inner,
    c : i32
}

fn print_inner_value(mut o : Outer) {
    println!("o.s.x = {:?}", o.s.x);
    o.c += 1;
}

fn change_inner(mut o : Outer) {
    let new_i = Inner{x : 40};
    o.c += 2;
    //o.s = &new_i;
    print_inner_value(o);
    println!("new_i.x = {:?}", new_i.x);
    //o.c += 3;
}

fn main () {
    let orinal_i = Inner {x : 10};
    let mut o = Outer{s : &orinal_i, c : 0};
    o.c += 4;
    change_inner(o);
}
```

What I really want is for the line `o.s = &new_i;` to not be commented.

But if I do that, I get E0597 saying that new_i does not live long enough.

But it appears to live long enough, because if I instead uncomment `o.c += 3;` then I get E0382 saying that o.c cannot be used since it has been moved.

Clearly at `println!("new_i.x = {:?}", new_i.x);` line, value `new_i` is alive and value `o` was moved into a function that has ended so it should no longer be alive.

So the question is: Why moving a value shrinks the scope of it, but does not shrink the lifetime of it?

Comment: This specific code could be allowed. But you can rebind `o` to make it compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is assuming that the lifetime of `'e` represents the lifetime of `Outer`: it doesn't.

Instead, since a value `o` of type `Outer<'e>` contains a reference with a lifetime of `'e`, then the lifetime of this value `o` must be shorter (or equal) to `'e` -- lest the value `o` outlives the referred to element, and ends up with a dangling reference.

---

The real issue you are hitting is that the lifetime parameters of a function (`'e`, here) are determined by the caller, and *fixed* within the function itself.

When you create the instance `o` in `main`, a lifetime `'e` is calculated matching the lifetime of `orinal_i`.

Then, within `change_inner`, when you set about changing `o.s`, the type system requires that whatever reference you assign must have a lifetime greater than or equal to this predetermined `'e`, that is greater than or equal to the lifetime of `orinal_i`.

That the *value* of `o`, containing said reference, will soon disappear has no impact on the required lifetime.

This may be observed better by looking at the non-elided version of the function:

```rust
fn change_inner<'e>(mut o: Outer<'e>) {
    let new_i = Inner{x : 40};
    o.c += 2;
    //o.s = &new_i;
    print_inner_value(o);
    println!("new_i.x = {:?}", new_i.x);
    //o.c += 3;
}
```

The `'e` above is the lifetime of a reference *outside* the function, thus a lifetime which *outlives* the function. `new_i`, a variable created within the function, has a shorter lifetime than `'e`, and therefore `o.s` *cannot* be bound to `&new_i`.

Another way to see it is that scope of `o` has an impact on how long `orinal_i` is borrowed for, but does not impact the lifetime of `orinal_i`: whether `o` lives a short or long life, it does not change how long the life of `orinal_i` is, just how long `o` accesses `orinal_i`.

---

In your particular case, a work-around exists: creating a new `Outer` value.

A new value can have a new *type*, one in which the `'e` parameter is NOT fixed, and the compiler will be able to infer a new "value" for the lifetime, a value shorter than that of `&new_i`:

```rust
fn change_inner<'e>(o: Outer<'e>) {
    let mut neo = o;

    let new_i = Inner{x : 40};
    neo.c += 2;
    neo.s = &new_i;

    print_inner_value(neo);

    println!("new_i.x = {:?}", new_i.x);
}
```

Here, the compiler selects a lifetime for `neo`'s `'e` which works for both `o.s` and `&new_i` -- the shorter of the two, really.

Do note there's quite a bit of magic at play:

- You'd expect `neo = o` to imply that `neo` has exactly the same type as `o`, yet the compiler infers a different lifetime for `neo`'s `'e`. This is specific to lifetimes, other generic parameters would be strictly equal. You can see `neo = o` as shorthand for `neo = Outer { s: o.s, c: o.c }` in this case.
- Strictly speaking `neo` outlives `new_i` so you'd expect `&new_i` not to be assignable to `neo.s`. The compiler is free to coalesce lifetimes together, however, and here does so, determining that `neo` and `new_i` live as long as each other.

Comment: `'e` is not invariant, it's covariant.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: I think not. When determining `'e`, covariance is at play indeed, however within `change_inner`, `'e` is invariant: no adjustment is allowed any longer. This does not prevent assigning a reference with a longer lifetime (covariance), but doing so will _not_ alter `'e` itself.

Comment: This is not related to variance, this is related to the fact that the type of `e` cannot change. If we would rebind it (`let o = o;`) variance would come into play, and the code would indeed be compiled.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Okay, so it seems we agree on the basic ideas, but we disagree on the use of the word _invariance_ here. I must admit not being well-versed in computer science, so I my usage may not be correct. I used _invariant_ because within `change_inner` the "value" of `'e` is fixed. How would you suggest describing this, otherwise?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: You are right, rebinding will make it compile, but does this rebinding allocates values on the stack? Or is it zero cost abstraction?

Comment: @E.Timotei: Whether something is really a zero cost abstraction generally hinges on whether the optimizer manages to peel away the layers of abstraction, so it's really hard to say. Notably, whether the stack or registers are used will depend on the actual size of the `Outer` struct (small ones are passed by registers), and whether the space of `o` is reused or not will depend on the optimization level and the optimizer. The _worst_ case is a stack-to-stack copy, and that's typically cheap for not-too-large structs.

Comment: I'd describe it as "because `'e` is fixed to be the [probably insert the non-elided version of the function here] and cannot change during the function".

Comment: @MatthieuM.: please add to the answer the solution itself, the rebinding, and put the whole example that will compile without errors (with the o.s = &i_new; uncommented). The detail that I was missing was that rebinding is able to change the lifetime and mutability of the value.

Comment: @E.Timotei: _The detail that I was missing was that rebinding is able to change the lifetime and mutability of the value._ => No, it's not. Rebinding is creating a _new_ value, with a new type.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Done, and good idea about the non-elided version.